# Sidebar links for different pages

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, menus, customization, sidebar

Hey all i am wondering what i need to add in order to have a different sidebar for a set page?

I created a category for the page (**called PatientEdu**):

[image: patcat]

And made sure the page was linked to the category:

[image: patcat2]

But it still seems to be using the other category sidebar (Which i also do not know where its at)?

[image: parcat3]

So any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

My current sidebar.php code is this:

```
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('default-sidebar')) : ?>
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Default Sidebar</h2>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('default-sidebar'); ?>    
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the function code:

[image: function]

**update 2**

Looks like its using the single.php page to populate the sidebar?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>                        
    <div id="sidebar">
       <h3><?php echo get_cat_name(CAT_DOCTORS); ?></h3>
           <ul class="info-list">
             <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <li <?php if ($post_id == get_the_ID()) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                 <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
               </a>
             </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
           </ul>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a new sidebar by pasting this into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
register_sidebars( 'id' => 'patientedu' );
```

Create a file called `sidebar-patientedu.php` and paste the following into it:

```
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('patientedu')) : ?>
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>PatientEdu Sidebar</h2>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('patientedu'); ?>    
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then paste this whereever you want your sidebar to show up:

```
<?php get_sidebar('patientedu'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, WordPress automatically creates a sidebar for your template if one is not defined (by creating a `sidebar.php` in your theme).

Secondly, you can register multiple sidebars by using [`register_sidebars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) in your `functions.php` file.

The template function, [`get_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar), accepts a parameter, `$name`, which determines which sidebar file to get. For example, if you have a file in your theme folder called `sidebar-doctors.php`, you can call `<?php get_sidebar('doctors'); ?>` in your theme and get the doctors sidebar.

You can use these techniques together to build a different sidebar for different template pages.

Or! You can go one step further and add the following code and make a `sidebar-<cat_slug>.php` for each category. If there isn't a php file with that name, WordPress will default to its own `sidebar.php`

```
<?php
if (is_category( ))
{
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
    get_sidebar($yourcat->slug);
}
?>
```

I hope this helps, and that I didn't completely miss the mark on your question.

Comment: You're off to a good start with your functions.php file and with your sidebar.php. Where you're checking `if (is_active_sidebar('default-sidebar'))` of course change "default-sidebar" to whatever you need to like "logos-sidebar". About your single.php, I would comment out the code inside div#sidebar and put in the snippet I wrote in my answer.